# How can I query for a value based off of key in JSONArray using stream api

Tags: java, json, java-stream

I have a json array with json objects having elements -id and values.Something like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "123",
        "value": "test",

    },
    {
        "id": "223",
        "value": "test12",

    }
]
```

I need to query the JSONArray and find the value where id = 123.

I tried stream api but its giving me "Unhandled exception : org.JSOn.JSonException '.

```
JSONArray jsonResponse = new JSONArray(response.asString());   
List<JSONObject> jsonItems = IntStream.range(0, jsonResponse.length()).mapToObj(index -> (JSONObject) jsonResponse.get(index)).collect(Collectors.toList());
 jsonItems.forEach(arrayElm -> arrayElm.get("id").equals("123"));
```

its giving JSOnexception at 'jsonResponse.get(index)' and at  'arrayElm.get("id")'.

Comment: Maybe `jsonResponse.length()` should be `jsonResponse.length()-1`?

Comment: The size of ```jsonResponse``` is 2, but I think the index is 1.

Comment: This code would work only if I can get rid of the json exception- IntStream.range(0, jsonResponse.length()).mapToObj(JSONObject.class:: cast).filter(o ->o.get("id").equals("123")).findFirst();  Json exception is showing as compile error which is not allowing me to run my code

Comment: Finally was able to suppress json exception but now getting missing return type error :(  JSONObject jsonItem = IntStream.range(0, jsonResponse.length()-1).mapToObj(JSONObject.class:: cast).filter(o -> {
                try {
                    return o.get("id").equals("123");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }   
            }).findFirst();

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution will be create an object corresponding to Json string. Use Jackson framework to convert from Json string to Object. Each object will have fields like id,value and other parameters. Finally, you will get an array of your object. Now iterate each object and check to get the required value or you also use Java 8 lambda to find the desired value. Besides, if you want to create an object for your json string, follow the link.

http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in previous answer, It is always recommended to have a Java Object corresponding to JSON String instead of relying more on programmatic way to parse/read JSON values. Below may be a convoluted solution for the above problem. This is not a recommended solution, just more like a puzzle solving.
Also I think you have an additional comma
`"value": "test"` `,`
which I have excluded below.

```
    public String getJsonNodeValue(String id) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        return Arrays.stream(("[{\"id\": \"123\", \"value\": \"test\" },{ \"id\": \"223\", \"value\": \"test12\"}]"
                        .replace("[", "")
                        .replace("]", "")
                        .split("},")))
                        .filter(node -> {
                            try {
                                JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(node + "}");
                                return id.equalsIgnoreCase(jsonNode.get("id").asText());
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                return false;
                            }
                        }).findFirst().orElse(null);
    }
```